# Cannot find libcocos2d ios.a library in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, build, coco2d-x

I have downloaded the cocos2d-x 3.6 yesterday. And I do follow the steps in this tutorial page: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game.

I build and run my new project in Xcode successfully. But I notice that there is no "libcocos2d ios.a" library existed when I click my project setting. I try to search the answer from internet, but it seems doesn't have correct one.

One more thing, if I clean the whole project and rebuild it. It will compiling 621 source files to come out(I think it's cocos2d source files), it takes too long time! I don't want to wait so long every time when I clean and rebuild project. Is there a way to make it don't rebuild cocos2d-x source files every time?

the screenshot:
[image]

--------------- environment ---------------
Xcode 6.3.2
Mac OS 10.10.3
cocos2d-x 3.6

---

I find a possible solution here:
http://mcspot.com/build-cocos2d-x-static-library-on-ios/

After trying, the Xcode project failed to link those two generated "libcocos2d ios.a" files(one for arm7, the other for arm64). I still don't know why this happened. I am building project for iPhone 6(arm64), why it says require i386 architecture.

here is the error (build for iPhone 6 simulator):
[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried to compile it without cleaning? Because it should work no problem. I always have cocos library marked red and it still works. Just don't clean the project, you don't need it. If you won't clean it, only your part will rebuild so whole compile time becomes minimal.

Comment: Ya, I know if I don't clean the project, it will be faster. but sometimes I have to. Because sometimes Xcode will "remember" the old object or resource instead of the new one. I can't explain why, but it did happen often.

Comment: Sometimes, I didn't clean the project. It will compile those 621 source files again too. I don't know why.... I just modify the size of a image. Really wasting my time............

Comment: I seems find an answer here. I am trying his solution. l will post the result later...
http://mcspot.com/build-cocos2d-x-static-library-on-ios/

Comment: after trying the solution above. the Xcode project failed to link those two  generated "libcocos2d ios.a" files. I don't know why..........

Comment: You may want to edit your question with your findings and trials. Not everyone reads comments.